# where is safe to step on in attic

Tags: attic

please see attached picture. Is it safe to step on the angled wood support highlighted in red box?[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes - these are elements of the truss system which holds up your roof. Usually, any 2x4 you find in an attic is safe to step on - except for small pieces uses to mount vent pipes.

Comment: I second this. One thing to add though is to make sure that the 2x4 is attached. I have occasionally seen boards in attics that aren't attached at all!